# Inputting a row which number is in a variable

Tags: sas

I have an array t that specifies numbers of rows that I want to read from file.txt. So my code should look like this:

```
data a;
   do i = 1 to dim(t);
      infile "C:\sas\file.txt" firstobs = t(i) obs = t(i);
      input x1-x10;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Of course this solution (firstobs) works only if the number of a column is a constant. How can I do this using an array (which is also read from the same file - from the first row)?

For example if the file.txt looked like this:

```
2 4 6 . . . . . . .
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Then I want the output to be:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Do you mean the first line of the file contains line numbers and you only want to read the records in the file referred to by the line numbers in the first record? If this isn't what you want then try showing some example input data with some corresponding output data, as well as expanding on your explanation of what you want please.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the first row contains the list of rows to keep.  It would probably be easier to read that from a separate file, but you could make it work with a single file.  You did not mention how to know the number of columns of data or the maximum number of row numbers that could be in the first row.  For now let's assume that you can set these numbers in macro variables.

Let's get your example data into a file:

```
options parmcards=tempdata ;
filename tempdata temp;
parmcards;
2 4 6 . . . . . . .
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
;
```

Now let's read it into a dataset.

```
%let ncol=9 ;
%let maxrows=1000;
data want ;
  infile tempdata truncover ;
  array rows (&maxrows) _temporary_;
  if _n_=1 then do i=1 by 1 until (rows(i)=.);
    input rows(i) @;
    drop i;
  end;
  else do;
    input x1-x&ncol;
    if whichn(_n_,of rows(*)) then output;
  end;
run;
```

If the other rows of the file have invalid data such that the INPUT statement would cause errors you can skip trying to read the data from those rows with a minor modification in the ELSE block.

```
  else do;
    input @;
    if whichn(_n_,of rows(*)) then do;
      input x1-x&ncol;
      output;
    end;
  end;
```

If you find that you frequently want to not read lots of records at the end of the file you could add this line to the end of the data step to stop when you have read past the last line you want.

```
  if _n_ > max(of rows(*)) then stop;
```

Comment: Ok, but here you read all rows and output only those which are in the first row. I don't want to do that. I want to avoid reading other rows.

Comment: There is no way to avoid reading all of the rows of a sequential file. You could avoid trying to convert the text in the row into variables, but you would still have to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer similar to Tom's, but which does not attempt to read in off-path data.  This may be superior for cases where your skipped rows have data which are not formatted in the same manner as your on-path data.  It uses Tom's parmcards and structure so you can more easily see the differences.

```
options parmcards=tempdata ;
filename tempdata temp;
parmcards;
2 4 6 . . . . . . .
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
;

%let ncol=9 ;
%let maxrows=1000;
data want ;
  infile tempdata truncover end=eof;
  array rows (&maxrows) _temporary_;
  do i=1 by 1 until (rows(i)=.);  *read in first line, just like Toms answer;
    input rows(i) @;
    drop i;
  end;
  input ;  * stop inputting on the first line;
           * Here you may need to use CALL SORTN to sort row array if it is not already sorted;
  _currow = 2;              * current row indicator;
  do _i = 1 to dim(rows);   * iterate through row array;
    if rows[_i]=. then leave; * leave if row array is empty;
    do while (_currow lt rows[_i] and not eof);  * skip rows not in row array;
      input;
      _currow = _currow + 1;
    end;
    input x1-x&ncol;    * now you know you are on a desired row, so input it;
    output;             * and output it;
    _currow = _currow + 1;
  end;
run;
```

You may as I noted above have to use CALL SORTN, if the array is not already sorted (i.e., if the missings are not at the end and the numbers are out of order).

Comment: It would be much easier to just move the actual INPUT statement after the IF statement.   `input @; if whichn(_n_,of rows(*)) ; input x1-x&ncol; output;`

Comment: I think the above would be slightly faster, though, since I don't have to query `whichn` each time.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is structured (i.e. same delimiter/one continuous 'row' of input data ) then the approach below should work.  I'm sure that you can tweak to make a bit more efficient but I put some comments in to explain what each section is doing.  I also suggest reading through the [`infile`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm) documentation for an explanation of the `_infile_` automatic variable and other ways to manipulate the input data buffer.  Also, if your input data file needs split up into individual rows itself then you will need to adjust for that.

```
filename in_data 'C:\sas\file.txt';

data out_data (keep=x1-x10);
    infile in_data;
    input fn;

    /*get the number of vars based on delimiter*/
    count = count(strip(_infile_), ' ') + 1;

    /*iterate through vars*/
    do i =1 to count;

        /*set new value to current var*/
        rec = scan(strip(_infile_), i, ' ');

        /*set array values to new value*/
        array obs(10) x1-x10;
            do j=1 to dim(obs); 
                obs(j) = rec;
        end;

        /*output to dataset*/
        output out_data;
    end;
run;
```

#### Input

```
2 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 2 3
```

#### Output

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I don't think OPs actual data contain just the row number.  Seems like OP wants to read in row 2,4,6, not just put 2s in the row.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Assuming I know the number of columns (10) and number of rows (10) I can get what I wanted using the following code:

```
data a;
     w=1;
     infile "C:\sas\file.txt" n=10;
     input #w x1-x10;
     array x(*) x1-x10;
     array t(10) _temporary_;
     do i=1 to 10;
         if(x(i)^=.) then t(i)=x(i);
         else leave;
     end;
     do j=1 to i-1;
         w=t(j);
         input #w x1-x10;
         output;
     end;
     stop;
run;
```

What is left is to do the same without knowing numbers of rows and columns. This way I only read the rows I'm interested in as opposed to reading all rows and only outputting the ones I need.

Comment: It saves nothing to "only read the rows I'm interested in".  What takes time is to read the lines from the file into memory. The operating system will read the lines in blocks. Files as small as this example will fit in one disk I/O operation.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a lot easier program to maintain if you just read the whole matrix into a dataset and then used the row numbers to pick the data you want. Your file would probably need to have hundreds of thousands of observations for the time saved to be worth the programming effort to avoid reading the full file.

Here is one way using the POINT= option of the SET statement to select the rows.

```
options parmcards=tempdata ;
filename tempdata temp;
parmcards;
2 4 6 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
;

data rows;
  infile tempdata obs=1 ;
  input row @@;
  row=row-1;
run;
proc import datafile="%sysfunc(pathname(tempdata))" dbms=dlm out=full replace;
   getnames=no;
   delimiter=' ';
   datarow=2;
run;
data want ;
  set rows ;
  pointer=row ;
  set full point=pointer ;
run;
proc print; run;
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it if I have it in a sas set. I wanted to do exatcly what 'point=' does, but when reading from a .txt file

Comment: It is impossible to do POINT= from a text file.  You might be able to it from a file with fixed length records, but nobody really uses those anymore.